# What is void (*)() type and how to cast to such a type

Tags: c++, pointers

What is `void (*)()` type in c++, how to cast a int to such type, I found it in a function like this:

```
function(const char*, long int, void (*)());
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

Comment: It's not specific to C++, it applies to C as well.

Comment: @g.tsh: Except that in C, the type would be `void(*)(void)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++ the 'maximum munch' rule applies in evaluating expressions: from the starting point go left as much as possible to get a valid expression, then go right.

This is how a---b translates to (a--)-b and not a-(--b)

Back to your expression

```
void (*)()
```

- `(*)` -> you have a pointer
- `(*)()` -> you have pointer to a function what takes no parameters
- `void (*)()` -> you have pointer to a function what takes no
  parameters and does not return a value

So, your function is passed in a pointer to a function with no parameters, that returns nothing. Careful when passing in the pointer because it need to match exactly(return type and all).

Now, as far as to why you would want to do this, I can give you an practical example: the `pthred_create` function prototype:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

void *start_routine() is what the tread will run (like it's main) and that's why the create function needs this function pointer.
Some APIs use this method for more flexibility

Answer (score 3):

It's a function pointer: the address of a function with no parameters or return value.

You can't meaningfully cast an `int` to such a type. It's for passing a pointer to your own code for the function to call:

```
void my_callback() {/* do something */}

function("Hello", 42, my_callback);
```

Now the function can call its parameter as if it were a function, with the effect of calling your "callback" function.

Comment: Hi, I got error saying `invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'long int'`

Comment: @user4016367: That sounds like you passed a function where an integer was expected, either because you got the arguments out of order, or forgot the `()` if you meant to call it. Check that the argument types match the function declaration. If you can't figure out what's wrong, post the code that caused the error so we don't have to guess.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the traditionally, `void (*)()` serves the same role for pointers to functions as `void*` does for pointers to data.  (This use is only traditional, however.  The standard guarantees that any conversion from one pointer to function type to another, then back to the original, will work.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I've never heard of that tradition, and it sounds completely out of place in C++ (where we have templates, rather than freaky error-prone casts, if we want more generic function types), so I won't be mentioning that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: It's the return type of WinAPI's `GetProcAddress`, the counterpart of POSIX `dlsym`. I agree it's a C-ism.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I've mostly seen it in C myself, but it goes back a long way.  (There are very few programs which require it; I think almost every time I've seen it, it has been in some sort of interpreter.) The usual tradition in C++ would be a pointer to an abstract base class; templates wouldn't apply in any of the cases where I've seen it, since the whole point has been runtime resolution.